# ksh script + print argument content in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I want to run the `script.sh` with one argument.

If the first argument = action then `script.sh` will print the action parameter - `restart machine each 1 min`

My example not work but please advice what need to fix in the script so I will print the `$action` parameter if argument is `action`.

Remark I not want to set the following solution - `[[ $1 = action ]] && echo action "restart machine each 1 min`

My example script:

```
  #!/bin/ksh
  action="restart machine each 1 min"
  echo  "action" ${$1}
```

Example how to run the script

```
  ./script.sh action
```

Expected results that I need to get :

```
    action restart machine each 1 min
```

Comment: Your requirement is contradictory.  To paraphrase your question: "I want to check if the first argument is 'action' and, if so, print a sentence, but I do not want to use the solution that checks if the first argument is 'action' and then prints a sentence."  Why do you not want to use test $1 = action && echo ...?

Comment: hi William - its because I want a simple code/syntax , and the second point is that I have allot of arguments more than 50 !!! , so to perform 50 diff tests is not Beautiful action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with `pdksh` this works:

```
echo  "action" `eval echo '$'$1`
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use eval:

```
action="restart machine each 1 min"
eval echo $1 \$$1
```

Note that doing something like this is a huge security risk.  Consider what happens if the user invokes the script with the first argument "; rm -rf /"

You can probably alleviate such problems with:

```
eval "echo '$1' \"\$$1\""
```

but really you're just asking for trouble  (This last version will struggle if the first argument contains a double-quote, and a $() construct will permit an arbitrary command to be executed).  It is much safer to simply use a case statement and check that the argument matches exactly a string that you are looking for.  Or, at least check that the argument you are eval'ing does not contain any of the following characters: `;()$"'`.  It's probably safest to check that it only contains alphanumerics (`a-zA-Z0-9`)

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years, but here's an example of using `nameref` (a.k.a. `typeset -N`).
It includes three consecutive tests for validity of the given argument.

1. Is an argument given?
2. Does the argument match a known variable?  `nameref` checks this.
3. Does the target variable have a value set?

```ksh
action='This is the value of $action'
word='This it the value of ${word}'
list='This is a list'
lie='This is a lie'

(
typeset name=${1:?Usage: script.sh varname} || exit 
nameref arg1=${name} || exit

: ${arg1:?} || exit

echo "$name $arg1"
)
```